# PhoneGap ICS black-screen on text element tap

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my PhoneGap app, whenever I tap an input text or a textarea my app goes all black, except for the title bar.

This problem only occurs in ICS phones.
The same code in Android <= 2.3 work as expected, Android (3.0) tablets not tested.

Locally building PhoneGap 1.8.1
Any idea?

P.S.: This happens even in the simpliest HTML codes, with just an input text.

Comment: have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=black+screen+in+android)

Comment: Is a quite simple search, I already searched over here for an answer before posting and btw.. is not a native app, is a PhoneGap one.